# Что конкретно означает слово "exports" в gulp'е?

Tags: gulp

Перешел на новый синтаксис Gulp, и не понимаю, что означает новое слово exports? Это что-то на подобии назначения тасков? То есть например: **exports.scripts = scripts;**  это присвоение таску функции?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_exports

Answer (score 0):

[module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) – это объект, который фактически возвращается в результате вызова `require`.